# Differentiate between Circles and Radio buttons Opencv python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a task to detect  Circles and Radio buttons in an Image. For this I tried Hough circles by having different parameters.

**Issues**: If the circles in the Image are of same radius of Radio buttons both are detected, but in our case it should only detect only one.

Is there a way to differentiate between circles and Radio buttons (when they are not checked).
Right now I am limiting them by Radius with 2 different functions one for circle and one for radio button.
The above code is for circles

```
    circle_contours=[]
    # Converting the image Gray scale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Blur the image to reduce noise
    img_blur = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)
    # Apply hough transform on the image
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img_blur, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1,20, param1=50, param2=20, 
    minRadius=11, maxRadius=21)
    # Draw detected circles
    if circles is not None:
       circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0, :]:
       # Draw outer circle
       cv2.circle(image1, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (34, 255, 34), 2)
       circle_contours.append(circles)
```

I have used a similar approach for radio buttons but with different parameters as below.

```
    radio_buttons= cv2.HoughCircles(img_blur, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1,20, param1=50, param2=16, 
    minRadius=9, maxRadius=10)
```

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdxDM.jpg)

Image 1:

[image: Image1]

Image 2:

[image: Image2]

For the Image1 it detects circles correctly and when it is passed to the radio buttons function it also draws circles(Image2) for the inner part of it with a reduced radius which are also detected as radio buttons

In [Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1Z94.png)Image3 it has to detect Circle and Radio buttons, where my code is only able to detect circles.

I have also tried using draw contours but it had issues when the Image also has checkboxes.

Is there any other approach or a better way for detection?

Comment: Share original image file in lossless format (png), please..

Comment: @AlexAlex I have added the picture to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Find and draw all the contours in the answer-sheet.

---

2. Apply `HoughCircles`

---

**Step #1:** We could start with finding all contours in the given [answer-sheet](https://content.zipgrade.com/static/pdfs/ZipGrade20QuestionV2.pdf).

- `contourIdx=-1` means to draw all the contours.
- ```py
  import cv2
  import numpy as np

  image = cv2.imread('zip_grade_form.png')

  # Converting the image Gray scale
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

  ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(src=gray, thresh=127, maxval=255, type=0)

  contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image=thresh,
                                         mode=cv2.RETR_TREE,
                                         method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

  gray = cv2.drawContours(image=gray, contours=contours, contourIdx=-1,
                       color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=2)
  ```

  Result:
- [image]
- From above we can see that all features except circles are removed. We use the `findContours` method to remove unwanted artifacts.

**Step#2:** Apply `HoughCircles`. The same code you wrote on the question. Result:

- [image]

### Code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('zip_grade_form.png')

# Converting the image Gray scale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(src=gray, thresh=127, maxval=255, type=0)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image=thresh,
                                       mode=cv2.RETR_TREE,
                                       method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

gray = cv2.drawContours(image=gray, contours=contours, contourIdx=-1,
                        color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=2)

cv2.imwrite("gray.png", gray)

img_blur = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img_blur, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, param1=50, param2=16,
                           minRadius=9, maxRadius=10)

circle_contours = []

if circles is not None:
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0, :]:
        # Draw outer circle
        cv2.circle(image, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (108, 105, 255), 2)
        circle_contours.append(circles)


cv2.imwrite("circles.png", image)
```

### **Update**

- For detecting check-boxes and radio-buttons you need to calculate the `contour-perimeter` (p) and the `contour-approximation` (a). [source](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html)
- We can separate each object using `p` and `a` value since each object has a unique `p` and `a` values.
- For instance, in image-3,

  - check-box: `p`= 73 and `a` = 4
  - radio-button: `p` = 64 and `a` = 8.
- You can find the values observing the code.
- Apply the 1st step again.

  - Result:
  - [image]
- Now find the contours in the above image:

  - ```
    if len(approx) == 8 and int(p) == 64:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (180, 105, 255), 3)
    elif len(approx) == 4 and int(p) == 73:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (180, 105, 255), 3)
    ```
  - Result:

    - [image]
  - Code:

    ```py
    import cv2

    from imutils import grab_contours as grb_cns
    from imutils import resize as rsz

    image = cv2.imread('K1Z94.png')

    # Converting the image Gray scale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(src=gray, thresh=127, maxval=255, type=0)

    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image=thresh.copy(),
                                            mode=cv2.RETR_TREE, 
                                             method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    gray = cv2.drawContours(image=gray, contours=contours, contourIdx=-1, color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=2)


    resized = rsz(gray, width=300)
    ratio = gray.shape[0] / float(gray.shape[0])

    canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 200)

    thresh = cv2.threshold(src=canny, thresh=60, maxval=255,
                       type=cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    cns = cv2.findContours(image=thresh.copy(), mode=cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    cns = grb_cns(cns)

    for c in cns:
         p = cv2.arcLength(c, True)  # perimeter
         approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * p, True)

         M = cv2.moments(c)

         # check if the all values of M are 0.
         all_zr = all(value == 0 for value in M.values())

         if not all_zr:
             cX = int((M["m10"] / M["m00"]))
             cY = int((M["m01"] / M["m00"]))
             c = c.astype("float")
             c *= ratio
             c = c.astype("int")

             # Circles: (radio-buttons)
             if len(approx) == 8 and int(p) == 64:
                 cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (180, 105, 255), 3)
             elif len(approx) == 4 and int(p) == 73:
                 cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (180, 105, 255), 3)

      cv2.imwrite("result.png", image)
    ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It answered one of my Questions But the issue is with other Images i.e Image 4 in my post where it has to differentiate 2 kinds of shapes i.e  Circles, and Radio Buttons.

Comment: I'm a opencv noob. This solution is not working in any other image other than on which you wrote code, anything which we need to change? TIA

Comment: @ChiragGupta The solution posted here as an answer is not accurate for all problems. You may need to change the parameters according to your situation. Like `ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(src=gray, thresh=127, maxval=255, type=0)` maybe changing the `thresh` from 127, 90, or any other integer might solve it. Error and trial way.

Comment: @Ahmet thanks for the comment I did that by trial and error and help from other stack answers. Cheers!